# Retriving User info using Webapp2 Auth

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, webapp2

I'm learning how to implement user login in GAE following the instruction in http://gosurob.com/post/20024043690/gaewebapp2accounts.

Below is a portion of the code that creates a user aware handler that my other handlers are supposed to inherit. This allows me to simply return user info by self.user. Now my question is how do I retrieve the user info in a ndb class which obviously inherits ndb.Model rather than BaseHandler. Please advise. Thanks!

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def dispatch(self):
    # Get a session store for this request.
    self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

    try:
        # Dispatch the request.
        webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        #super(BaseHandler,self).dispatch()
    finally:
        # Save all sessions.
        self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

   @webapp2.cached_property
   def auth(self):
     return auth.get_auth(request=self.request)

   @webapp2.cached_property
    def user(self):
       user = self.auth.get_user_by_session()
       return user

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def user_model(self):
       user_model, timestamp = self.auth.store.user_model.get_by_auth_token(
              self.user['user_id'], 
              self.user['token']) if self.user else (None, None)
       return user_model
```

---

```
class Global_Var(ndb.Model):   #<<< This is the ndb class from which I want to use the user info.
    current_user = ndb.StringProperty()

    @staticmethod
    def get_id():
        return user['email']   #<<< This, of course, errors out since user is not defined in this class
```

Comment: This doesn't really make much sense. Why can't you just pass the user to the model class when you need it? How are you hoping to use the get_id method?

Comment: You are absolutely right. :) Thanks!